# unable to start project using npm start

Tags: reactjs

its been hours trying to run or start npm server so i can customize my project and preview changes when i use "npm start" command i get this error :

```
internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:888
  throw err;
  ^

Error: Cannot find module 'webpack-cli/bin/config-yargs'
Require stack:
- C:\Users\Mazen\Desktop\DigitalMenu\node_modules\webpack-dev-server\bin\webpack-dev-server.js
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:885:15)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:730:27)
    at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:957:19)
    at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:88:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\Mazen\Desktop\DigitalMenu\node_modules\webpack-dev-server\bin\webpack-dev-server.js:65:1)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1068:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1097:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:933:32)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:774:14)
    at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (internal/modules/run_main.js:72:12) {
  code: 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND',
  requireStack: [
    'C:\\Users\\Mazen\\Desktop\\DigitalMenu\\node_modules\\webpack-dev-server\\bin\\webpack-dev-server.js'
  ]
}
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! @ start: `webpack-dev-server --mode development`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the @ start script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\Mazen\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2021-05-16T22_33_30_318Z-debug.log
```

This is my package.js file:

```
{
    "private": true,
    "scripts": {
        "start": "webpack-dev-server --mode development",
    "dev": "webpack serve",
        "development": "cross-env NODE_ENV=development node_modules/webpack/bin/webpack.js --progress --hide-modules --config=node_modules/laravel-mix/setup/webpack.config.js",
        "watch": "npm run development -- --watch",
        "watch-poll": "npm run watch -- --watch-poll",
        "hot": "cross-env NODE_ENV=development node_modules/webpack-dev-server/bin/webpack-dev-server.js --inline --hot --disable-host-check --config=node_modules/laravel-mix/setup/webpack.config.js",
        "prod": "npm run production",
        "production": "cross-env NODE_ENV=production node_modules/webpack/bin/webpack.js --no-progress --hide-modules --config=node_modules/laravel-mix/setup/webpack.config.js"
    },
    "devDependencies": {
        "@babel/plugin-proposal-class-properties": "^7.12.13",
        "@babel/preset-react": "^7.12.13",
        "axios": "^0.21.1",
        "babel-plugin-transform-class-properties": "^6.24.1",
        "babel-preset-react": "^6.24.1",
        "babel-preset-stage-1": "^6.24.1",
        "bootstrap": "^4.6.0",
        "browser-sync": "^2.26.14",
        "browser-sync-webpack-plugin": "^2.0.1",
        "cross-env": "^7.0.3",
        "jquery": "^3.2",
        "laravel-mix": "^5.0.9",
        "lodash": "^4.17.20",
        "popper.js": "^1.12",
        "react": "^16.14.0",
        "react-dom": "^17.0.2",
        "resolve-url-loader": "^3.1.2",
        "sass": "^1.32.6",
        "sass-loader": "^8.0.0",
        "vue-template-compiler": "^2.6.12",
        "webpack": "^5.37.0",
        "webpack-cli": "^4.7.0",
        "webpack-dev-server": "^3.11.2"
    },
    "dependencies": {
        "@stripe/react-stripe-js": "^1.4.0",
        "@stripe/stripe-js": "^1.13.1",
        "moment": "^2.29.1",
        "moment-timezone": "^0.5.32",
        "ng2-charts": "^2.2.5",
        "react-live-preview": "0.0.8-alpha",
        "react-loading-overlay": "^1.0.1",
        "react-native-web": "^0.16.3",
        "react-notification-system": "^0.4.0",
        "react-paypal-button-v2": "^2.6.3",
        "react-paystack": "^3.0.3",
        "react-redux": "^7.2.2",
        "react-responsive-carousel": "^3.2.18",
        "react-router-dom": "^5.2.0",
        "react-scripts": "^4.0.3",
        "react-spinners": "^0.10.6",
        "react-stripe-checkout": "^2.6.3",
        "react-stripe-elements": "^6.1.2",
        "react-toast-notifications": "^2.4.0",
        "react-toasts": "^3.0.6",
        "redux": "^4.0.5",
        "redux-logger": "^3.0.6",
        "redux-persist": "^6.0.0",
        "redux-thunk": "^2.3.0",
        "rtl-css-js": "^1.14.1",
        "use-dynamic-refs": "^1.0.0",
        "yarn": "^1.22.10"
    }
}
```

i have done a research i have changed the "start" script to "webpack serve" but it also gave other errors  now am stuck here and not sure what the problem is, Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**In your package.js file, there were some bugs.**

```
{
    "private": true,
    "scripts": {
        "start": "webpack-dev-server --mode development"
    }, //<-------------------------------------------------------
    "dev": { //<-----------------------------------------------------
        "webpack serve",
        "development": "cross-env NODE_ENV=development node_modules/webpack/bin/webpack.js --progress --hide-modules --config=node_modules/laravel-mix/setup/webpack.config.js",
        "watch": "npm run development -- --watch",
        "watch-poll": "npm run watch -- --watch-poll",
        "hot": "cross-env NODE_ENV=development node_modules/webpack-dev-server/bin/webpack-dev-server.js --inline --hot --disable-host-check --config=node_modules/laravel-mix/setup/webpack.config.js",
        "prod": "npm run production",
        "production": "cross-env NODE_ENV=production node_modules/webpack/bin/webpack.js --no-progress --hide-modules --config=node_modules/laravel-mix/setup/webpack.config.js"
    },
    "devDependencies": {
        "@babel/plugin-proposal-class-properties": "^7.12.13",
        "@babel/preset-react": "^7.12.13",
        "axios": "^0.21.1",
        "babel-plugin-transform-class-properties": "^6.24.1",
        "babel-preset-react": "^6.24.1",
        "babel-preset-stage-1": "^6.24.1",
        "bootstrap": "^4.6.0",
        "browser-sync": "^2.26.14",
        "browser-sync-webpack-plugin": "^2.0.1",
        "cross-env": "^7.0.3",
        "jquery": "^3.2",
        "laravel-mix": "^5.0.9",
        "lodash": "^4.17.20",
        "popper.js": "^1.12",
        "react": "^16.14.0",
        "react-dom": "^17.0.2",
        "resolve-url-loader": "^3.1.2",
        "sass": "^1.32.6",
        "sass-loader": "^8.0.0",
        "vue-template-compiler": "^2.6.12",
        "webpack": "^5.37.0",
        "webpack-cli": "^4.7.0",
        "webpack-dev-server": "^3.11.2"
    },
    "dependencies": {
        "@stripe/react-stripe-js": "^1.4.0",
        "@stripe/stripe-js": "^1.13.1",
        "moment": "^2.29.1",
        "moment-timezone": "^0.5.32",
        "ng2-charts": "^2.2.5",
        "react-live-preview": "0.0.8-alpha",
        "react-loading-overlay": "^1.0.1",
        "react-native-web": "^0.16.3",
        "react-notification-system": "^0.4.0",
        "react-paypal-button-v2": "^2.6.3",
        "react-paystack": "^3.0.3",
        "react-redux": "^7.2.2",
        "react-responsive-carousel": "^3.2.18",
        "react-router-dom": "^5.2.0",
        "react-scripts": "^4.0.3",
        "react-spinners": "^0.10.6",
        "react-stripe-checkout": "^2.6.3",
        "react-stripe-elements": "^6.1.2",
        "react-toast-notifications": "^2.4.0",
        "react-toasts": "^3.0.6",
        "redux": "^4.0.5",
        "redux-logger": "^3.0.6",
        "redux-persist": "^6.0.0",
        "redux-thunk": "^2.3.0",
        "rtl-css-js": "^1.14.1",
        "use-dynamic-refs": "^1.0.0",
        "yarn": "^1.22.10"
    }
}
```

**If it is not working, try this way.**

1. remove `"webpack": "^5.37.0","webpack-cli": "^4.7.0","webpack-dev-server": "^3.11.2"` in json file.
2. `npm install --save webpack webpack-cli webpack-dev-server`
3. `npm start`

**If not working again. add this in scripts.**

```
"scripts": {
  "build": "webpack --config webpack.config.js"
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply, but unfortunately nothing works, the first solution gave error on the whole file "it should be JSON file not only javascript file"-the error, the seconed and the third still the same first error. also the "dev" is part of "script"